# Upload to github before exit

Tags: winedt

I want to auto upload my workcopy to github before I exit WinEdt, currently I can do this by hand. And I try to add the following in WinEdt's `Exit.edt` (just before the END):

```
  Run('git add .', '%P', '', 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('git commit -m "%!F"', '%P', '', 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('git push origin master','%P', '', 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
```

It seems that it not work for me.

Comment: You might need to specify a full path to git.exe, depending on if the `PATH` variable you use at a regular command prompt is inherited by WinEDT or not.

Comment: Do you have github's directory in the Windows' path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are using for WinEdt's `Run` macro is not completely correct.

In fact, the third argument should be a 0/1 parameter and not a string.

Also, you are using the variable `%!F` which is an empty string if you don't have any document set as main file. You should use `%F` instead.

So, the following should work:

```
  Run('git add .', '%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('git commit -m "%F"', '%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('git push origin master','%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
```

If it doesn't, this means that the path to `git.exe` is not in Windows' `PATH` variable, and you have to specify the full path when calling it:

```
  Run('"<path-to-git>\git.exe" add .', '%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('"<path-to-git>\git.exe" commit -m "%F"', '%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
  Run('"<path-to-git>\git.exe" push origin master','%P', 0, 0, 'git', 1, 1, 1);
```